# How to fix the EoF error in this python program?

Tags: python, module, passwords, eof, nameerror

It is password generator program in python-3. It will auto generate the password in random char, after we want enter that password as input. If it is correct access is granted otherwise... But i have eof error in "if statement" it prints the denied option whatever input is given. Help to solve my code

```
import random
char = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'
length = input('password lenght?')
len = int(length)
for p in range(1):
    pas = ' '
    for c in range(len):
         pas += random.choice(char)
         g = pas
    print (g)
code = input("Enter password :")

if g == code:
    print("Access Granted")
else:
    print("Access Denied")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `pas`  with empty string not with a space.

```
import random
char = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'
length = input('password lenght?')
len = int(length)
for p in range(1):
    pas = ''
    for c in range(len):
         pas += random.choice(char)
    g = pas
    print (g)
code = input("Enter password :")

if g == code:
    print("Access Granted")
else:
    print("Access Denied")
```